# How to pass a variable value from parent ngOnint() component to child component?

Tags: angular

[image: parentComponent.ts]
[image: childComponent.ts]

I want to get the value of "user" variable value in child component.

thanks for the Help!

Comment: Can you add some code snippet about what you want to achieve?

Comment: recommend you to read this : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Really "parent not pass a variable to child". it's "child get a variable from parent"

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `user` object as an `@Input` to the child component.

Class:

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{

  @Input() user: SocialUser;

}
```

Template:

```
<app-child [user]="user"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer value from parent to child using 3-different way

1. Using input
   in parent .html file

   ```
   <app-child [user]="user"></app-child>
   ```

   and child.ts file

   ```
   export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
     @Input() user: SocialUser;
   }
   ```
2. Using Simple Storage
   storage.service.ts

   ```
   public user: String = '';
   ```

   Now import this service in the module.ts file and In parent.ts import storage service

   ```
   constructor(public storageService: StorageService){}
   ngOnInit(){this.storageService.user = 'user_value';}
   ```

   In child.ts file

   ```
   constructor(public storageService: StorageService){}
   ngOnInit(){console.log(this.storageService.user);}
   ```
3. Using Observable
   In storage.service.ts

   ```
   public user: Subject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
   ```

   Now import this service in the module.ts file and In parent.ts import storage service

   ```
   constructor(public storageService: StorageService){}
   ngOnInit(){this.storageService.user.next('user_value')}
   ```

   In child.ts file

   ```
   constructor(public storageService: StorageService){}

   ngOnInit(){
      this.storageService.user.subscribe(user=> {if(user) console.log(user)});
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the parent component into the child component.

https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-navtree

Doc shows example clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> In Angular you can pass data from **parent** to **child** component using
>   @Input decorator.

**Step1**: Parent component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit  {
  user:string;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user='sanjay'
  }
 }
```

**Step2**: Child component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template:'<h1>{{user}}</h1>',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.scss']
})
export class TestComponent {
   @Input() user:string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parent and child or not in direct relationship - you can inject the same service in your child and get the `users` data like you did in your parent

If they have relationship - you can pass data to the child `component` selector using `@Input()` property

**loginHandler.component.html**

`<app-profile-handler [childUser]="user"></app-profile-handler>`

**profileHandler.component.ts**

```
export class ProfileHandlerComponent {
   @Input() childUser: SocialUser;
}
```

Hope this helps you - Happy coding :)